# how to insert the data in sendmail_table by retrieve email column values from User_table?

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures

I have two tables `user_table` and `sendmail_table`.

In `user_table` there are 4 columns:

1. `name`,
2. `username`,
3. `email`,
4. `password`

and in `sendmail_table` there are 3 columns:

1. `emailid`,
2. `subject`,
3. `body`.

My question is how to insert the data in `sendmail_table` by retrieve `email` column values from `user_table`?

I would like a stored procedure for this.

Please help me out.

Comment: You'll have to provide more information - which RDBMS, example data, expected result, ...

Answer (score 0):

In general you use insert command:

```
Insert Into sendmail_table(emailid, subject, body)
  Select <your columns list> From user_table.
```

But how would you tell which part of your email in user table is subject and body is up to you. You can substring subject and body...